# OOP Construct Advice with Children Using Different Structs

Tags: c++, oop

I have a module with a parent class we'll call Parent and a bunch of children we'll call A, B, C. All of the children need to be able to send data in a byte array, the only difference is that they all have a different struct that they use and all implement their own function to transform that struct of data into a byte array. My problem is that I feel like I haven't correctly implemented this OOP system as I'm copying and pasting code and only changing one function that is called, something that I'm sure could be implemented through templates, as well as the fact that I feel like the Parent class should have the transform function as a purely virtual function; however, I can't seem to figure out a way to do that cleanly. I'll paste some example code of something similar to what I have below:

```
class Parent
{
    virtual void fillTxBuf() = 0;
    void sendData()
    {
        //This fills txBuf with the data specific to the class
        this->fillTxBuf();
        send(txBuf);
    }
    uint8_t txBuf[20];
}

class A final: public Parent
{
    void fillTxBuf() override
    {
        this->transformStructToBytes(this->aDataStruct, this->txBuf);
        //Some other code that is the same in every "fillTxBuf" function
    }

    //I want this function to be an overrride as every child should implement this
    void transformStructToBytes(A_DATA, uint8_t*)
    {
        //Implementation goes here and is different for each child
    } 
    A_DATA aDataStruct;
}

class B final: public Parent
{
    void fillTxBuf() override
    {
        this->transformStructToBytes(this->bDataStruct, this->txBuf);
        //Some other code that is the same in every "fillTxBuf" function
    }

    //I want this function to be an overrride as every child should implement this
    void transformStructToBytes(B_DATA, uint8_t*)
    {
        //Implementation goes here and is different for each child
    } 
    B_DATA bDataStruct;
}
```

As you can see there is a lot of code here that is being copy and pasted unnecessarily (I think) and I was wondering if somebody could help me to eliminate this redundancy and possibly give pointers on how they would structure this. Thanks in advance for the help, I'm just trying to better my programming!

Comment: I think this question is off-topic for StackOverflow. If you have some working code that you're not happy with, [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be more appropriate. Be sure to leave a link to the CodeReview post if you decide to post there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll be sure to do that next time.

Comment: Asked similar question on CodeReview, here is the [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/236047/purely-virtual-function-with-different-return-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
class Parent
{
public:
    void sendData() const
    {
       std::vector<uint8_t> buf = getFlattenedBytes();
       send(buf);
    }

protected:
    // Should be implemented by each child class
    // to return a
    virtual std::vector<uint8_t> getFlattenedBytes() const = 0;
}

class A final : public Parent
{
protected:
    virtual std::vector<uint8_t> getFlattenedBytes() const override
    {
       std::vector<uint8_t> ret;
       // code to add flattened representation of aDataStruct
       // into (ret) would go here
       return ret;
    }

private:
    A_DATA aDataStruct;
};

[... and so on...]
```

Comment: Oh wow, this was much easier than I was thinking, thanks a bunch! Also, one more question: if you wanted a function to unflatten the bytes i.e. go from vector<uint8_t> to A_DATA or B_DATA how would you recommend go about making that a purely virtual function like above?

Comment: @achilles7744 Taking some bytes and trying to figure out whether they're an `A` or a `B` or a `C` is not so simple (and probably deserves its own question if you want something flexible and extensible). The simplest approach is just a switch. If the first byte is `0` then `A`, if the first byte is `1` then `B`, etc but this has many problems. Although, if you already know that some array of bytes is a `B` then it becomes trivial. You'd just have a function (it doesn't need to be virtual) that takes the array of bytes and initializes the struct.

Comment: I'll make a new question and link it here, thanks for the help.